# How to open arbitrary Facebook user profile by user ID

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have i.e. this Facebook user ID: 183063665433467. Loading it in browser needs this url: "https://www.facebook.com/183063665433467"

How can I open this profile and not my own profile to Facebook native app?

Tried string like: "`fb://profile/%@`" and "`fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=%@`". First does not work at all, second opens my own profile.

Comment: There is no supported way